# Using filter with empty values in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, select-by-attribute, filter

In my script, at the moment of having the layers loaded, I filter all the ToC layers with a unique value for all the layers.

I use the `setSubsetString('"FIELD" = \' VALUE \ '')` [method](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aba0ee124dcf2d037f3af53d99866c01c), but when it does not find any field with that value, it throws me the following error:

> wkb outbounds

How can I solve this? I am using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Try using `" \"FIELD\" = 'VALUE' "`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you call the `setSubsetString` method, but
did you try something 'lighter' like the following?

```
"Field" like '%VALUE%'
```

Comment: yes, but I still send the error, when my layer does not find features that match the expression.